# C program not compiling in vs code mac no such file or directory

Tags: c

This thing comes whenever I try to compile though I downloaded mingw w 64 it shows this only what to do

[image: strong text]

Comment: Please paste the actual text instead of screen shot. This makes it much easier for us to help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose file names that contain space in quotes or escape the space with `\`